# How to upload a Excel file and insert data from that file into the database at the same time in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a program that upload the .xls file and store it into the database.
My problem is when i give a static path to the argument then it works fine and inserts the data into the database.
but when i get the file-name dynamically then it shows error LIKE..
 Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\FileUpload\newEmptyPHPWebPage.php on line 22
The filename is not readable

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include 'db_connection.php';
        include 'reader.php';
        $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    ?>

        <table border="1">
        <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                }

                        $excel->read($name);
            $x=2;
            while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
                $Testcase_id = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][1]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][1] : '';
                $Testcase_title = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][2]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][2] : '';
                $Testsuite_id = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][3]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][3] : '';
                                $Circle_id = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][4]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][4] : '';
                                $Testcase_desc = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][5]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][5] : '';
                                $Date_created = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][6]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][6] : '';
                                $Created_by = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][7]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][7] : '';
                                $Type = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][8]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][8] : '';
                                $Priority = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][9]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][9] : '';
                                $Precondition = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][10]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][10] : '';
                                $Test_step = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][11]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][11] : '';
                                $Expected_result = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][12]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][12] : '';
                                $Request_mode = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][13]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][13] : '';
                                $Language = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][14]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][14] : '';
                                $Category = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][15]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][15] : '';


                // Save details
                $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO test_case_master ".
       "(Test_case_id , Test_case_title, Test_suite_id, Circle_id, Test_case_desc, Date_created,Created_by,type,priority,preconditions,Test_steps,Expected_results,Request_mode,Language,Category) ".
       "VALUES('$Testcase_id' , '$Testcase_title', '$Testsuite_id', '$Circle_id', '$Testcase_desc', '$Date_created','$Created_by','$Type','$Priority','$Precondition','$Test_step','$Expected_result','$Request_mode','$Language','$Category')";
                $result_insert = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_insert) or die(mysqli_error()); 

              $x++;
            }
        ?>    
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume you cannot open the file until it saved on server. Please save the file some where on server and try to write the desired code. Best Luck

Comment: But it works fine if i write like this.. $excel->read('hello.xls'); so, if i store the file on the server then after at the time of insertion of file into the database won't i face the same problem because i woud have to perform this same code.

Comment: i tried to put the file into the same directory as the php file.still it gives the same error and another one ""Undefined index: file;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the file upload working there are a few things to remember. First the form you submit needs to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise the file is not recognized by PHP. After you did that the undefined index warning should disappear. Second you need to move the uploaded file from the temp directory PHP uploaded it into to a directory where you can access the file. Use `move_uploaded_file()` for this task (for examples see the PHP docs). Then you cann access the file using the directory you moved it into and its name.

Comment: Muller. Thank you for the answer.I have updated the code for the uploading the file.

Answer (score 0):

As @Markus suggested i have use following code to upload the file and store it on the locle server.

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
$filename = basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    print "Upload failed!";
    } 
}
```

and Following code for the get the file from the directory and insert into the database.

```
$dh = opendir("uploads/");
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
if($file == $filename){
         $excel->read($target_dir . $file);
     }
}
```